# Ansible Installing Python Mysql Connector

Tags: mysql-python, ansible

I'm using Ansible to automate the tasks to backup a mysql database and when running the `mysql_db` tasks I'm getting this message: `msg: the python mysqldb module is required`

So, after to many attempts to install `python-mysqldb` using Ansible tasks I've tried to install it manually executing the command `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` and I got the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-mysqldb
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64bits

What am I doing wrong?

What's the way to install `python-mysqldb` using `apt-get`?

Comment: Try to do it with `pip install mysql-python`.  It's usually better to install python packages this way as not all linux distros support every python package...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ubuntu 13.04 has been end-of-lifed for about 10 months.](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/01/28/ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-end-of-life-reached-on-january-27-2014/) As the link says, "**No more package updates will be accepted to 13.04**". You should use Ubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 14.04, which are LTS (long-term support) versions.

Still, for this *specific* problem, as @phantom said, use pip.

```
- pip: name=MySQL-python
```

(note the capitalization)

Comment: Understood. One more question, what if I don't have installed the pip? 
I've tried with `easy_install: name=pip` but I get this `msg: Failed to find required executable easy_install`.
Sorry if these questions are to obvious

Comment: that's okay. Try it with this: `sudo apt-get install python-pip`. Obviously, you can turn that into a recipe if you want.

Comment: yes, I know that but how would it be in Ansible style?
`apt: pkg=python-pip state=installed` I guess, right?

Comment: Finally, I've updated my Ubuntu version to 13.10 which I was able to upgrade at Digital Ocean. Now `apt: pkg=python-mysqldb state=installed` is working as well

Comment: Why would you install this with pip if you can install it with a package via `apt` ?